# Swiftlint underscore name swift

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I use `swiftlint` in my project. The project name is `ABC xx` and it works fine with swiftlint. Now I decided to include `Unitest` in my application and I have to import `@testable import ABC_xx` into the swift test file which is `class ABC_xxTests: XCTestCase {` not I get an error with Swiftlinter which says `Type Name Violation: Type name should only contain alphanumeric characters: 'ABC_xxTests' (type_name)` how do I sort this error

Comment: You can do `//swiftlint:disable:this type_name` just for this one?

Comment: would this be included in my appDelegate or where?

Comment: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#disable-rules-in-code

Comment: `//swiftlint:disable:this type_name
class ABC_xxTests: XCTestCase {` still shows the same error

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following swiftlint rule enable the use of underscore in your Swift class names:

```
type_name:
  allowed_symbols: "_"
```

**EDIT**:
If you want to enable the use of underscore also for variable names use:

```
identifier_name:
  allowed_symbols: "_"
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @carmine's answer, keep the below two things in mind while adding attributes to any rule in `.swiftlint.yml`:

- it should be listed in a new line
- and should be preceded with a white space.

In my case I overlooked the white space before `allowed_symbols`. So the linting was not working. When I added white space, it was successful.

Answer (score 2):

Use of **underscore** for variable names add in **.swiftlint.yml**:

```
variable_name:
     allowed_symbols: "_"
```

Comment: Tested with SwiftLint 0.39.2 : `'variable_name' rule has been renamed to 'identifier_name' and will be completely removed in a future release.`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable rule for specified folder, in your case its an ABC_xxTests folder. Inside `.swiftlint.yml` configuration file you can use 'excluded' property. If you haven't yet create swiftlint configuration file, you can create one with name `.swiftlint.yml` and place it in your project root folder.

Add this lines:

```
excluded:
    - ABC_xxTests
```